# How can I retrieve image link from google drive and upload it on MongoDB using GridFS?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, gridfs

I am planning to upload my logos on my Google Drive and want to serve those logos using my website. I am using MongoDb As Database and my plan is to read link of logo image from my Google Drive and want to save it on collection of MongoDB so that it will render on my website dynamically. How is it possible through GridFS?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, However you will have to do a lot of setup to your system can query data from google drive

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

You need to have to create a link between your data and google drive file id and store it at mongodb